# Custom field is unable to appear in issue view screen

Tags: jira, custom-fields, jira-plugin

I've created a jira custom field plugin to appear at issue view screen only (as there will be predeined calcualtion on field description-javascript).

But this does not appear at issue view screen what i need even though, assgined hard coded values in vm file.

when create "edit.vm" then it appears on edit issue screen and after assigning the value to field , it could appear in issue view screen but, without edit template , its not working and unable to see in issue view screen.

Below is atlassina-plugin xml stuff:

```
<customfield-type name="Summary field" i18n-name-key="cascading-summary-field.name"    key="cascading-summary-field"    class="com.company.plugins.jira.customfields.CascadingSummaryCustomField">
<description key="cascading-summary-field.description">The cascading summary field to allow    multiple summary fields using five text box and description javascript to write related text to    appear in summary field.</description>
```

View template as below: (with hard coded value specified though unable to appear this on issue view screen).

```
<span>$<input type="text" name="${customField.id}:input1" id="${customField.id}:input1"    value="#if($input1)$input1#end"  style="border: 0px;width:59px;margin-left:1px;"/></span>
<span>$</text><input type="text" name="${customField.id}:input2" id="${customField.id}:input2"    value="3"  style="border: 0px;width:59px;margin-left:1px;"/></span>
<span>$</text><input type="text" name="3" id="${customField.id}:input3" value="0"  style="border:    0px;width:59px;margin-left:1px;"/></span>

//also, tried by just keeping <span>some value</span>
```

how it could resolve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As found, field to appear at view screen, there must have require "Edit" template.

so, it resolved by creating an edit template.

Other wise, have to follow achieve by preparing dynamic object through jquery under CUSTOM FIELD'S description field.  (first found, related position to append through firebug and append that created object inside "Custom field >> description".

Thanks